# text is not highlighted when i open a new browser window in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Until about a week ago when I opened a new browser window in Chrome the address bar text was highlighted.  I use new tab redirect and it opens to chrome://apps but in the last week the text is not highlighted so I have to do it manually if I wish to go to a web address, which is tedious and I forget because I'm used to it already being that way (highlighted).  I've googled this and asked in other forums and I've uninstalled and re-installed new tab redirect and it's not fixed.  I'm sure there's something simple that can solve this.  Anybody?